# O que significa uma sinalização 'disputada'?

Tags: suporte, filas-de-análise

Na página de sinalizações do usuário, o que significa uma sinalização 'disputada'?

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É quando a você sinaliza algo mas a análise é concluída de forma que a decisão é de manter a publicação, entretanto a decisão não é unânime. Exemplo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso a decisão dos analisadores da fila foi de "Parece OK" e a publicação foi mantida no site, mas houveram vários votos para excluir, logo, quem sinalizou isso teve a sinalização marcada como "disputado".

O fato do exemplo acima ter vários "Recomendar exclusão" e ainda assim a decisão ser de "Parece OK" provavelmente é pelo fato da resposta estar com pontuação positiva, o que deu um peso maior para os votos de "Parece OK".

Comment: Eu acho que 6 "recomendar" excluiriam a resposta, mas como ali só tem 5 ela foi mantida.

Comment: @bfavaretto mas dois "Parece OK"s  geralmente também não são o suficientes para encerrar a análise, não tenho certeza da quantidade necessária, mas é mais do que dois.

Comment: Talvez 7 análises seja o limite, não tenho certeza.

Comment: Era bom saber @bfavaretto

Comment: @JorgeB. Essas coisas não são tão bem documentadas, precisa escavar o [meta.se].

Comment: O @Gabe deve saber...

Comment: @JorgeB. [São 6 mesmo](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145292/167534).